# how to code a string to a unique number and decode it

Tags: string, hash, decode

Is there any way to code a long string to a unique number (integer) and then decode this number to original string? (I mean to reduce size of long string)

Comment: Put the string in a DB table and use a corresponding numeric ID

Comment: Sounds a bit like [Huffman-Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).

Comment: Use Hashmaps to link your string to a integer. You will have to make it your own encoding to make it "unique"

Comment: using DB, I should save both string and id. so the size is more than original string!!!

Comment: You mean how to compress a 1-Kb string to a 4-Byte integer without loosing information? With such an algo you would get rich :-)

Comment: yes. I think you are right :-(

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no.

The complex answer is maybe.

What you are looking for is compression, compression can reduce the size of the String but there is no guarantee as to how small it can make it. In particular you can never guarantee being able to fit it into a certain sized integer.

There are concepts like "hashing" which may help you do what you want depending on exactly what you are trying to do with this number.

Alternatively if you use the same string in a lot of different places then you can store it once and pass references/pointers to that single instance of the String around.

Comment: is there any way like md5 hashing with decoding way?

Comment: @user3212159 You can hash the string. You can't reverse that and go from the hash back to the string though. It just can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to hash it to string eg md5. Then you convert the characters of the hash string into numbers according to the alphabetical number

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).